# inverse laplace operator bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, laplacian, poissons-equation

Given $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d  $ open and bounded, we define the operator $T:L^2(\Omega) \to H_0^1 (\Omega)$ as $T(f)=u$ where $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the unique weak solution to the Poisson equation: $-\Delta u=f $ in $\Omega$  and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, meaning $\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot \nabla v dx = \int_\Omega fvdx$ for all $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Then, we define an inner product on $H_0^1(\Omega)$:
$$<f,g>_{H^{-1}}:=\int_\Omega fT(g)dx. $$

I need to show, that the linear operator $T$ is bounded and that the space $(H_0^1(\Omega), \|\cdot\|_{H^{-1}})$ is not complete. I've tried using the Poincare and Holder inequalities to show the boundedness of $T$. I get for $u=T(f)$:$$ \|u\|_{H_0^1}^2=\|u\|_2^2+\int _\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx\leq (c+1)\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx=(c+1)\int _\Omega fudx \leq (c+1)\|f\|_2\|u\|_2
$$ but I don't know how to proceed from here. Is there something obvious I am missing?

To show that the space is not complete, do I explicitely find a non-convergent Cauchy sequence or do I show that our norm here is equivalent to one with which our space is known to be non-complete?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer for showing $T$ is bounded. You almost had it actually. Let me use $Tf$ instead of $u$. From what you had,
\begin{align*} 
\int_\Omega |\nabla(Tf)|^2\, dx = \int_\Omega fTf\, dx & \le \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|Tf\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \\ 
& \le C\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\|\nabla(Tf)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}, 
\end{align*}
where we apply the Poincaré inequality (with constant $C$) one more time. This gives $\|\nabla(Tf)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\le C\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ and so
$$ \|Tf\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}\le \sqrt{C^2 + 1}\|\nabla Tf\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\le C\sqrt{C^2 + 1}\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much! With your help I've found a potentially simpler solution:
$\|u\|_{H_0^1}^2=\|u\|_2^2+\int _\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx\leq (c+1)\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx=(c+1)\int _\Omega fudx \leq (c+1)\|f\|_2\|u\|_2  \leq (c+1) \|f\|_2 \|u\|_{H_0^1}$

Now dividing both sides by $\|u\|_{H_0^1}$ gives us $\|u\|_{H_0^1}\leq (c+1)\|f\|_2$, which in the case $u=0$ of course still holds.